# How to automatically insert data to a MySQL table when data is inserted to another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a Quiz script with three tables: "questions", "options" and "connections".

Table name: **questions**

```
Question_ID    Question
10             Sample Question 10
11             Sample Question 11
```

In the "questions" table, Question_ID is set as primary key.

Table name: **connections**

```
Connection_ID   Quiz_ID   Question_ID   Question_Order
1               1         10            27
2               1         11            28
```

In the "connections" table, Connection_ID is set as primary key and Quiz ID is always 1.

Now, what I want is that when I insert data into the table "questions",  relevant data be inserted into the table "connections" automatically. After adding two more rows of data into "questions"(Qn ID:12, 13), the table "connections" should look like this:

```
Connection_ID   Quiz_ID     Question_ID     Question_Order
1               1           10              27
2               1           11              28
3               1           12              29
4               1           13              30
```

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: even when you declared an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER FOR EACH ROW, how should the system know which quizid is to insert

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I corrected it.

Comment: What is wrong with doing an additional query in your PHP?

Comment: @nbk Here Quiz_ID is the same. All other values need to be increased by 1.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It adds one row of data only. ie, If I insert Qn IDs 12,13,14, then only the values for the last ID (14) is inserted to "connections".

Comment: @Ajesh So write an additional query for each ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i saifd an AFTER INSERT trigger

the main Problem that everything is added to quiz id 1, i think you shoud have that also in your question table

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS newquestions;
 DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE TRIGGER newquestions
AFTER INSERT
DETERMINUISTC
ON questions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(Connection_ID),MAX(Question_Order) INTO @connect,@questionorder FROM connections WHERE Quiz_ID = 1;
    INSERT INTO connections VALUES(@connect + 1,1,NEW.Question_ID,@questionorder + 1) ;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use MYSQL triggers. And You have to set Quiz ID and Question Order needs to manage based on your need.

Currently, you can set `Connection_ID` and `Question_Order` AUTO_INCREMENT.
Then set the below trigger.
DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_questions_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON questions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO connections(Quiz_ID, Question_ID)
        VALUES(1,NEW.id);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```